# Laravel put request getting blank response in api

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-10

**Route Code:**

```
Route::put('update-service/{id}', [ServicesController::class, 'update']); // To Update Service
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public function update(Request $request, string $id)  
{  
    return ([$request, $id]);  
}
```

**Request Body:**

```
{  
    'name':'Waiting Area',  
    'description':'Service Description 3'  
}
```

**& Response is:**

```
[  
    {  
        "attributes": {},  
        "request": {},  
        "query": {},  
        "server": {},  
        "files": {},  
        "cookies": {},  
        "headers": {}  
    },  
    "9"  
]
```

For now, as a response, I only want to get request values.

Answer (score 0):

This code will return an array containing the request data and the ID.

```
public function update(Request $request, string $id)  
{  
    return [$request->all(), $id];  
}
```

Or if you want only the $request data (and not the ID)...

```
public function update(Request $request, string $id)  
{  
    $requestData = $request->all();

    return response()->json($requestData);
}
```